# Collision Detection in SpriteKit + Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am making a simple Pong game using SpriteKit + Swift. Right now I am trying to detect when the ball hits the edge of the screen. When I run my code and the ball hits the edge of the screen, for some reason the score increases twice instead of once. For example the console reads

```
Player 1 has a score of: 1.
Player 1 has a score of: 2.
```

when I hit the right side of the screen once.

My code in the didBeginContact function:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    var firstBody = SKPhysicsBody()
    var secondBody = SKPhysicsBody()

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    } else {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }

    if firstBody.categoryBitMask == ballCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == leftSideCategory {
        player2Score++
        print("Player 2 has a score of: \(player2Score).")
    } else if firstBody.categoryBitMask == ballCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == rightSideCategory {
        player1Score++
        print("Player 1 has a score of: \(player1Score).")
    }

}
```

Comment: check out this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24228274/why-are-didbegincontact-called-multiple-times

Answer (score 1):

Set the `firstBody.categoryBitMask` to something other than `ballCategory`.  Maybe something like `deadBallCategory` which is set to 0x0 (or 0, or however you define them, either way, set it to 0).  Then, your `firstBody` (the ball) won't keep triggering your `didBeginContact` function.  When you create a new ball to add to the scene, make sure to set the `categoryBitMask` to `ballCategory` (which it appears you do anyway).